# GPG decrypts file with no content/as empty file

Tags: encryption, gnupg, shell-exec

i am struggling with a gpg problem for a few days and cant figure out a solution by my own. i would be glad if you could help me out with the following issue:

i need to decrypt a gpg file in php. for that, i am using the following command:

```
cat passphrase.txt | /usr/local/bin/gpg --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 stammdaten.txt.gpg>stammdaten.txt

the passphrase.txt contains the password for decryption
stammdaten.txt.gpg is the encrypted file
the decrypted data will be written in stammdaten.txt

when i run this command in php:


shell_exec=("cat passphrase.txt | /usr/local/bin/gpg --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 stammdaten.txt.gpg>stammdaten.txt")


i get a zero-byte output file (stammdaten.txt) with owner=ftpadmin and group=psacln

but when i execute the same command via ssh terminal (as root), the data will be decrypted and written correctly with file owner=root and group=root.
```

i think, that this is a permission problem. how can i use that command in php correctly? i also tried to chown and chgrp with the ftprightson the decrypted file, but nothing seems to help.

every answer is highly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got it to work:

first of all, i changed the gpg command for decryption with echoing the passphrase into stdin:

```
$passphrase = utf8_decode('mypassphrase');
$encrypted = 'fullsystempathtogpgfile.gpg';

"echo '$passphrase' | /usr/local/bin/gpg -v -v --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --no-default-keyring $encrypted";
```

before executing with shell_exec i needed to change the homedir of gpg:

before it was set with:

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/var/www/.gnupg");
```

but obviously the php user (in my case "ftpadmin", found out with "whoami") has no permission to access that directory, so i copied the .gpg folder into my new created php user folder: /home/ftpadmin (with 777 perms) and changed the GNUPGHOME:

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/home/ftpadmin/.gnupg");
```

now i am able to decrypt the gpg files with php. maybe you could find some help for your similar issue. thanks again for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
cat passphrase.txt | /usr/local/bin/gpg --output stammdaten.txt --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 stammdaten.txt.gpg
```

instead.

Another thing you can try is to run this command in the shell as ftpadmin in the directory where your stammdaten.txt file is to make sure it is not a file permission problem.

```
su ftpadmin
cat passphrase.txt | /usr/local/bin/gpg --output stammdaten.txt --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 stammdaten.txt.gpg
```

Comment: if i try your suggested command, i get gpg: Invalid option "--passphrase-fd0" and if i try to "su ftpadmin" nothing happens, i am still logged in as root. but when i "su www-data" i get switched and execute my initial command. the file owner and group then is "www-data", the file is written successfully. is it possible to execute my command as www-data?

Comment: the invalid option problem was my fault...the command works in shell, but not in shell_exec in php.